# Div row with 10 col div tags not fit properly?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

```
<div class="row">
<div class="row col 6">

<div class="col-sm-1">
<div class="col-md-3">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Added with col-sm-1 col-md-1 for different div tags, need to align properly.

Comment: The second line should be: `<div class="col-6">`, no?

Comment: yes , its my typing mistake